# I would like to create a 3D surface plot with input variables that have different ranges

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've received an answer, but the question was closed due to not enough detail. I'm adding more information, in case this helps someone.

I posted a simplified version of the function I am working on. I gave: f(q, t) = k*q(1-t), where k is just some pre-defined constant. I wanted to create a 3D surface plot of f(q, t) for all q and t, when q and t lie on different intervals.

q is on the unit interval and t can be any value from 0 to some positive value z (excluding 1).

I found similar questions and answers but they addressed variables that were on the same interval. Some of the steps were unclear even after looking at guides. Specifically, I did not know how to combine intervals for q because I am new and did not know what else to search.

I have only done basic 2D plotting with excel data before so I did not know where to start other than defining the function. Hope this is enough detail for someone with a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

def f(x, y):
    return 2 * x * (1 - y)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y = np.union1d(np.linspace(0, 0.99, 50), np.linspace(1.01, 2, 50)) 


X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.contour3D(X, Y, Z, 100, cmap='binary')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z');
```

Basically, you just need to adjust the example given here:
https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.12-three-dimensional-plotting.html.
The script is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: someone closed the question, so comment was deleted but thank you @ilyywa 
that resource you gave me is also great.